# PayPal Checkout.js popup OnCancel event fires automatically in Edge browser

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, paypal-sandbox

Description :

After the button is clicked and the popup finished loading, onCancel is called immediately and overlay disappears but the popup stays open.

I found some link in GitHub - https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/750 and already closed, telling us to change our internet/intranet settings and trusted sites. This may work for IE but not for Edge and we can also not tell customers to change settings on their browser before placing an order with us.

Code used (same as https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-flow/#, only added onCancel and onError):

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

 

paypal.Button.render({
//env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
env: 'sandbox',
client: {
//sandbox: 'AZDxjDScFpQtjWTOUtWKbyN_bDt4OgqaF4eYXlewfBP4-8aqX3PiV8e1GWU6liB2CUXlkA59kJXE7M6R',
sandbox: '@Model.ConfigData.PaypalClientId',
production: 'xxxxxx'
},
// Specify the style of the button
style: {
//layout: 'vertical', // horizontal | vertical
size: 'responsive', // medium | large | responsive
shape: 'rect', // pill | rect
color: 'blue' // gold | blue | silver | white | black
},

// Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
commit: true,

// payment() is called when the button is clicked
payment: function (data, actions) {
debugger;
// Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
return actions.payment.create({
payment: {
transactions: [
{
amount: { total: '@Model.CreditData.PaymentAmount', currency: 'USD' },
//invoice_number: 'TransactionID',
description: 'Your payment reference number is :' + 'TransactionID',
reference_id: 'InvoiceReference'
}
],
redirect_urls: {
return_url: window.location.protocol.replace(":", "") + "://" + window.location.host.replace("/", "") + '/' + window.location.pathname.replace("/", "") + '?Success=True&RawURL=' + 'returnValue',
cancel_url: window.location.protocol.replace(":", "") + "://" + window.location.host.replace("/", "") + '/' + window.location.pathname.replace("/", "") + '?Success=False'
}
}
});
},

// onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
var return_url = '';
// Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
actions.payment.execute().then(function () {
//console.log(data);
return_url = data.returnUrl;
});

actions.payment.execute().then(function (res) {
if (res.state === 'approved') {

}
else {

}
}).catch(function (error) {
console.log('onCancel');
console.log(error);
});
},
// Pass a function to be called when the customer cancels the payment
onCancel: function (data, actions) {
console.log('onCancel');
console.log(data);
},
onError: function (error) {
console.log('onError');
console.log(error);
}

}, '#paypal-button-container');

 

 

<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

Error -

[image]

Comment: This is working fine in all other browsers file but in Microsoft Edge browser it's giving error and when I analyzed then found PayPal checkOut.js OnCancel event get fired automatically in Microsoft Edge. So please help me on this.

Comment: Raised this concern in PayPal site as well but didn't get any response yet - https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/PayPal-Checkout-js-popup-OnCancel-event-fires-automatically-in/m-p/1797965/thread-id/48665

Comment: Please use `Javascript` tag instead of `C#`

Comment: Here we are passing Model value inside paypal checkout.js button code for payment and my application in MVC-c#

Comment: Same issue here - but in Chrome and using the newer sdk/js. This didn't happen a few days ago - feels like a flaky sandbox update.